# How to setup yeoman test for subgenerator that reads package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, yeoman

I have a subgenerator that uses the name from the package.json. Now I want to test that function and wrote a `before()` that is supposed to create a dummy package.json for the test.

Problem is that the subgenerator cannot read the dummy json file.

test file:

```
before(function (done) {

  helpers.run(path.join( __dirname, '../addcomponent'))
  .inDir(path.join( __dirname, './tmp'), function(dir) {

    fs.copyTpl(
      path.join(__dirname, '../app/templates/_package.json'),
      dir + 'package.json',
      { ProjectName: 'foo' }
    );

    var test = fs.readJSON(dir + 'package.json');
    console.log('test: ' + test); // returns the object
    console.log('test.name: ' + test.name); // returns the correct name

  })
  .withArguments(['foo'])
  .withPrompts(prompts)
  .withOptions(options)
  .on('end', done);

});
```

but in my sub-generator:

```
var memFs = require('mem-fs');
var editor = require('mem-fs-editor');
var store = memFs.create();
var fs = editor.create(store);

...

init: function() {
  this.pkg = this.fs.readJSON('package.json');
  console.log('this.pkg: ' + this.pkg); // returns undefined
}
// or
init: function() {
  this.on('ready', function() {
    this.pkg = this.fs.readJSON('package.json');
    console.log('this.pkg: ' + this.pkg); // returns undefined
  });
}
// or
anyOther: function() {
  this.pkg = this.fs.readJSON('package.json');
  console.log('this.pkg: ' + this.pkg); // returns undefined
}
```

The whole setup can be found here: https://travis-ci.org/markusfalk/generator-kickstart/builds/58892092

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: I'll keep the old answer underneath and that's probably relevant to most people running into this issue, but not to you.*

The idea behind `mem-fs` is to have an in memory store. It doesn't write anything to disk automatically. As so, it keep the state in the `mem-fs` instance. In this case, you're creating your own mem-fs instance, while yeoman use another instance. This mean the file you write is never seen by Yeoman (and never written to disk).

For you, the fix would be to use the generator instance provided as the first parameter of the `ready` event.

```
helpers.run(path.join( __dirname, '../addcomponent'))
  .on('ready', function (generator) {
    generator.fs.write('file.txt', 'foo');
  });
```

Another option is to use the node.js sync `fs` methods. (`fs.writeFileSync()`, etc)

---

My guess is you're using `this.fs.readJSON()` inside your generator constructor.

The constructor is initialized before the `ready` event is triggered. This mean you read the file before it is actually written.

The usual fix is to never read inside the constructor. You can delay this step until the `initializing` phase where the `inDir()` (or the `ready` event) callback has run.

As a side note, you should use `inTmpDir()` rather than `inDir()`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I added the various calls to ```this.fs.readJSON()``` to the orginal question above but none of them worked. I also never overwrote the constructor. You can see the whole file here: https://github.com/markusfalk/generator-kickstart/blob/master/addcomponent/index.js

Comment: I have added the definition of ```this.fs.readJSON()``` to the question above

Comment: That worked but I thought using the generator's fs will soon be deprecated? https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/766

Comment: Nope, you read that issue wrong. We're speaking about the legacy file system helpers, `this.copy`, `this.write`, etc. `this.fs` is the new shiny way to handle files in Yeoman.